# How do you upgrade your git installation using the windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, git, command-prompt, railsinstaller

I recently installed railsinstaller on my computer, but have noticed that the installation for git that came with the application is old. I wanted to install it through the git installer, but it never showed me where I would like for the location of git to be at. My other solution is to upgrade it through the command prompt without using the git installer. How do I do this? Which commands would I have to use in the command prompt terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing software from the command prompt isn't an easy task on Windows. First, you will need to find out what technology was used to create the installation package. Then you need to download a (UI based) tool which can modify the installation package to stop asking questions and just do what you want. It's certainly possible ... if you can spend a couple of hours or days to find out how.

Now the reason why the git installer isn't asking is probably because it detects an existing install and wants to upgrade it - since the "new" place must be the old place, no question is asked. To "fix" this, you can try to deinstall Git (Control Panel -> Installed Software -> Remove). When you run the installer again, it should give you more options.

If you just want to update the command line tools, you can also try to unpack the installer or install on a second computer. That should give you the `git.exe` plus all the DLLs and scripts which you can then copy manually. But Git on Windows also install a MINGW environment with a shell and to update that, you probably have to run the installer so it can make the necessary changes to the registry.

Comment: That worked. I only needed to do that in order to progress in setting up rails. Thank you.

Comment: What specifically is "that"? Uninstall/install or unpacking the files elsewhere?